# How to hide something in select?

Tags: sql, database

I have to print out the neighbour-countries of Germany. The output is a table including all neighbour-countries and Germany. Is there any way to hide  "Germany" or delete it but just from the "output-table"?

The border table which i refer to has two columns displaying the two countries which border each other.

Thats my code:

```
select Country.NAME 
from Country 
join Borders on Country.CODE = Borders.COUNTRY1 OR Country.CODE = Borders.COUNTRY2 
where Borders.COUNTRY1 = 'D' IN (select Borders.COUNTRY2 from Borders) 
OR Borders.COUNTRY2 = 'D' IN (select Borders.COUNTRY1 from Borders)
```

[My code and "output"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxf2I.png)

[Border Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k0Zu.png)

Comment: Please provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) an appropriate database tag; (4) your current query *as text*.

Comment: Your question is poorly asked. Do you mean something like `where NAME not in ('Germany')`. provide us with disierd output and some code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you would add your example data and sqlcode as text in the question. It is easier to answer by copying your code and changing it. The problem with hyperlinks ist that they can go dead in the future too. Anyway.

The easiest way is to add `where Country.CODE != 'D'`  to the end of your query.

The better way would be to change the condition a little bit:

```
select Country.Name 
from Country 
join Borders on 
    (Country.Code = Borders.Country1 and Borders.Country2='D') or 
    (Country.Code = Borders.Country2 and Borders.Country1='D')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name realy? i dont think so. We only want to get a result when its in the one column and 'D' in the other or the other way round. This way we dont have to filter germany out at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This might work but not tested

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
 CountryName
FROM 
 Country 
INNER JOIN Borders ON 
 Borders.COUNTRY1 = Country.CODE OR Borders.COUNTRY2 =  Country.CODE
WHERE 
 (Borders.COUNTRY1 = 'D' OR Borders.COUNTRY2 = 'D')
)
WHERE CountryName NOT LIKE '%Germany%'
```

Comment: I already found a way but thanks for the suggestion. Something with a where-clause would cause an error this way.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the `ON` clause should be that one of `country1` or `country2` in the table `borders` is equal to `'D'` and exclude from the results the country with `code = 'D'`:

```
select c.name
from country c inner join borders b 
on c.code in (b.country1, b.country2) and 'D' in (b.country1, b.country2)
where c.code <> 'D'
```